# MS Access 2013 front-end with MS SQL Azure backend write conflict error

Tags: sql-server, azure, ms-access

I have looked all over and can not find an answer to this problem. I have a MS Access 2013 Database frontend that work great with the backend. We needed access from multiple locations and so moved the backend to MS SQL Azure account with Microsoft.

Everything still works great except for one key thing; new records can be made, but they can not be updated. Records that existed before the migration CAN be updated. It is only NEW records that can not be updated. The error received is a Write Conflict error with a choice to drop changes or save them to the clip board.

I have experimented quite a bit trying to determine what the root of the problem might be to no avail. It is not bit value fields with null value fields. It does not have to do with Relationships. I'm really at a loss at this point. I hope someone can help.

Thank you.

Comment: I can only suggest some investigation that can shed some light on it. How are you connecting? (ADP or linked tables?). Are you using a single SQL user or windows authentication? What was the migration process to get the database up to Azure? Can you update the record directly in SSMS? It's very strange for this error to occur on some records but not others. It's not like Azure remembers which records are which

Comment: Thank you Nick for you comments. I am using linked tables with a single SQL user authentication. I went into SSMS and added a record from there and then updated it without error. So this would indicated the write conflict has something to do with the connection I suppose. I'm looking up the exact procedure I used to migrate the data to Azure. I'll share that when I find it.

Comment: I followed the procedure: http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/cloud/link-to-azure-sql-database.html

Comment: Error when editing via a form or directly table? Can you test both?

Comment: The guide you linked doesn't have a guide for moving existing in premise SQL data to an Azure database. It's a guide for connecting to an existing SQL Server database. What version of SQL, MS Access, and which ODBC driver are you using?

Comment: In your linked guide and all the way at the bottom of this amusing argument about OleDB vs ODBC, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ce92437b-da89-47d9-9bbf-38a84b74ee62/receiving-write-conflict-error-when-trying-to-update-linked-sql-server-table-that-contains-a?forum=accessdev there is mention that you should basically use the ODBC driver, not the Native Client driver.

Comment: Krish, both in the form and in the table directly.

Comment: Nick, I moved from a 2013 version of MS Access using the native Jet engine to SQL Azure. I'm using a SQL Server Native Client 11.0. I'll try the ODBC Driver for SQL server as you suggest and let you know how that goes.

Comment: So I tried using the ODBC Driver for SQL Server and I get the same error. I also noticed that when I try to update the record I added directly in SSMS I am able to update it from Access without throwing the Write Conflict error.

Comment: I figured it out. There was a bit field that had a default value of 0. Once 0 was entered manually the error stopped appearing. So although the field had a value, it was still seeing this field as Null. When I ran a query looking for null values on this field the new records with default zeros appeared alongside the null values. So now I just need to build something into the form to make sure that a value is saved and not null. If you know why this happened I'd love to hear it.